# Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in GRP php extension

Tags: php

Hi i am new to google cloud,
Working since 5days.
I make a collection on firebase has type google/cloud-firestore,
and i am using it in my php project.

It working fine.
but since 2 hour it showing error-

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\orDeal
>   Cloud\composer\vendor\grpc\grpc\src\lib\ServerStreamingCall.php on
>   line 48

I make a test.php file for testing database connection-

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/composer/vendor/autoload.php';
use Google\Cloud\Firestore\FirestoreClient;

$db = new FirestoreClient([
    'projectId' => 'myProjectId'
]);
$snapshot = $db->collection("users")->documents();
print_r($snapshot);
```

But still it showing error.

Comment: But i not get solution from that link.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your php.ini to increase the timeout

> max_execution_time = 300

or do it using [ini_set](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php) function

```
// Set timeout in seconds (0 = no timeout)
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

Comment: That will increase time of execution.

Comment: i am getting problem from grpc plugin.

Comment: Well "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\htdocs\orDeal Cloud\composer\vendor\grpc\grpc\src\lib\ServerStreamingCall.php on line 48" is the exact message PHP would give for a timeout. An extension that have its own timeout setting sounds strange and I don't think I have ever heard about that before.